# jquery tree traversal issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.field').blur(function() 
     $('*').not('.adress').click(function(e) {
                foo = $(this).data('events').click;
                if(foo.length <= 1) {
    //             $(this').next('.spacer').children().removeClass("visible");
                }
                $(this).unbind(e);
        });
});
```

I'm trying to remove a class "visible, whenever I'm bluring a field classed .field, unless if I click an element with the class .adress.

The field blur and adress-click is working as it should(I tired it with alert) but not the removal of class, does anyone know why?

The removal of class works if the not(".adress")-function is removed!
Like this:

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
   (this).next('.spacer').children().removeClass("visible");
});
```

Comment: To be clear, is your intention that you want to detect if I leave a `.field` ***by clicking on*** a `.adress`? That's what it sounds like from your question, but your code is actually attaching a `.click()` handler at the time of blurring, so two separate click events will have to be involved.

Comment: I want to detect if I leac a field except *by clicking on* a .adress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to remove a class "visible, whenever I'm bluring a field classed .field, unless if I click an element with the class .adress.

This is quite tricky.  What your current code is doing is binding is binding a `click` event handler every time you blur an element with the class `field`.  This won't work as you want it to.

The best cross-browser way I can think of to do this is to listen for `focus` events and log which element has received focus, taking action on the previously active element if desired:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curFocus;

    $(document.body).delegate('*','focus', function(){
        if ((this != curFocus) && // don't bother if this was the previous active element                
            ($(curFocus).is('.field')) && // if it was a .field that was blurred
            ($(this).is('.adress')) // the newly focused field is an .adress
        ) {
            $(curFocus).next('.spacer').children().removeClass("visible"); // take action based on the blurred element
        }

        curFocus = this; // log the newly focussed element for the next event
    });
});
```

This probably has pretty poor performance.  If you aren't worried about cross-browser compatibility, especially for old versions, [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement) may be of interest to you.

Comment: cool, I', trying to find out wich browsers support active element, we want to support IE7+ (and chrome safari firefox, but they generally beat IE) Do you know wich browsers support activeElement?

Comment: A little research has shown that `activeElement` will in fact do nothing for you here, because it is set *after* `blur` is called.  FWIW, IE is the most reliable supporter of it, because it was originally an IE proprietary feature, adopted by HTML5.  The method above is probably the best you'll get.

Comment: I tried to make it work, but it doesn't... Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot? Here is an url to a page: http://dev.resihop.nu/addtrip?from=as&to=&when=&name=&email=&phone=&details=&posted=&got_car=0

Comment: I added  alert(curFocus); and it returns Object HTMLInputElement, and only when I focus a field. This seems wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you've got an extra quote after `//$(this`.  you don't need to quote the `this` variable.

Additionally, your * selector can be simplified to `$(':not(.address)')`

Can you provide an example of your HTML?

Comment: sample: http://dev.resihop.nu/addtrip?from=&to=&when=&name=&email=&phone=&details=&posted=&got_car=1